# ITfoxtec Identity Packages' Documentation Location?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Is there simple documentation of the latest ITfoxtec Identity NuGet's, at least initialization and the API's, that can be used instead of solely looking at the example projects and trying to extract them?

Comment: Hi! Did you ever find good documentation?  I'm also trying to implment the ITfoxtec library and finding it difficult to figure out how it works and what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell I never did find any in depth documentation that would make using the NuGet an easy effort. What I ended up doing is download the solution from GitHub. It has a variety of project examples for different scenarios. I chose the TestIdPCore project to study as I am interested in the IdP role. What you need to know is that it is based on a .NET MVC project architecture and the most important interface elements are in the controllers which are the web interfaces. I am progressing, but slowly.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some dokumentation her https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2